# String update in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

Currently I have `varchar` field. The delimiter is "$P$P$".

The delimiter will appear at least once and at most twice in the `varchar` data.

Eg.

```
Sample Heading$P$P$Sample description$P$P$Sample conclusion

Sample Heading$P$P$Sample Description
```

If the delimiter appears twice, I need to insert a text before the second occurance of the delimiter.

Eg:

```
Sample Heading$P$P$Sample DescriptionINSERT TEXT HERE$P$P$Sample Conclusion
```

If the delimiter occurs only once, then I need to insert a text at the end of the field.

Eg:

```
Sample Heading$P$P$Sample DescriptionAPPEND TEXT HERE
```

How this can be done in SQL query?

Comment: Might I sugest three separate fields?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do a lot of string manipulation you might want to use a CLR (.net) function. Since SQL Server isn't exactly made for string manipulation.

Or even better, pull this data back to your application and do it in code.

I even think you can't do it using the default [SQL Server String functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181984.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The CharIndex function has an optional 3rd parameter that allows you to specify the starting position of the search.  You can use this to find the 2nd occurrence of a string using CharIndex. You can also use the stuff function to insert a string in to another string.

Example:

```
Declare @Temp Table(Data VarChar(8000))

Insert Into @Temp Values('Sample Heading$P$P$Sample description$P$P$Sample conclusion')
Insert Into @Temp Values('Sample Heading$P$P$Sample Description')

Select len(Data),
        CharIndex('$P$P$', Data + '$P$P$',CharIndex('$P$P$',Data) + 1),
        Stuff(Data + ' ', CharIndex('$P$P$', Data + '$P$P$',CharIndex('$P$P$',Data) + 1), 0, 'Text Here')
From   @Temp
```

I realize it looks like a mess, but I do encourage you to understand how this works because you may need something similar in the future.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using delimiters, why not creating 3 columns or if you only want one --> an xml field?